# javascript get function results outside of function

Tags: javascript, variables, global

```
$(document)/ready(function(){

if (this == that) {
var myobject = {};
var variable = 55;
function dothisandthat(variable);
alert(JSON.stringify(myobject));
}

})

function dothisandthat(variable) {
//Do something
myobject["first"] = variable + 5;
myobject("second") = variable + 10;

}
```

How can i get myobject to be used in my function, and then call the object outside of the function again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be globally available if you just do `myobject = {}` or `window.myobject = {}`, or even `$.myobject = {}`.  Attach it to some global object like window, or since you are using JQuery, the JQuery $ object, and then you can use that throughout.

Or as @Pointy said, just add the parameter to the method:

```
function dothisandthat(variable, myObject) {
```

Comment: ... or just pass "myobject" as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @Pointy, or use an OO approach ;)

Comment: @Pointy yep, true.  Code looked like a quick example, so I'm thinking the actual need is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with an object oriented approach, you would usually tell the object to modify it's internal state, which solves your scoping problems at the same time.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.first = 0;
    this.second = 0;
}

MyObject.prototype.doThisAndThat = function (variable) {
    this.first = variable + 5;
    this.second = variable + 10;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
    var myObject = new MyObject();

    myObject.doThisAndThat(55);
    alert(JSON.stringify(myObject));

    //...
});
```

However, if you want to use a functional approach (data and behavior lives separately) you must make `myObject` available in the `doThisAndThat`'s scope. There are a few ways to do this:

1. Pass the object as an argument to the function. That's usually the way I prefer since it makes dependencies explicit.

   *Please note that a pure functional approach would not mutate the object passed-in to  the function, but would return a modified copy of the object since data structures are usually immutable.*
2. Rely on a closure. In this case, you would simply have to move the `doThisAndThat` function declaration inside the document ready callback.
3. Rely on global variables or well-know objects. I would avoid this solution most of the time since it makes your dependencies hidden and your code harder to test.